# haproxy-https service can't bind socket on restart

Tags: haproxy

I have few haproxy services running and some of them couldn't restart properly for last 12 hours (and before they worked fine few days).
When I realize some service is down, I check `ss -tulpn` for a port listened - see that no one listens port in subject and trying to restart service:

```
# service haproxy-https restart
Shutting down haproxy-https:                               [FAILED]
Starting haproxy-https: daemon /usr/sbin/haproxy-https -D -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy-https.cfg -p /var/run/haproxy-https.pid
[WARNING] 294/170448 (22682) : Proxy 'httptat': in multi-process mode, stats will be limited to process assigned to the current request.
[ALERT] 294/170448 (22682) : Starting proxy httptat: cannot bind socket [0.0.0.0:3310]
[ALERT] 294/170448 (22682) : Starting proxy HTTPS: cannot bind socket [0.0.0.0:5008]
                                                           [FAILED]
```

I've googled error and tried all solutions found to no avail.

Here's the `/etc/haproxy/haproxy-https.cfg`

```
global
        daemon
    maxconn 5000
    nbproc 7
        log             127.0.0.1   local0 info
defaults
        mode tcp
        timeout connect 50000ms
        timeout client 500000ms
        timeout server 500000ms
        timeout check 5s
        timeout tunnel 50000ms
        option redispatch


listen httptat
bind 0.0.0.0:3310
        mode http
        stats enable
        stats refresh 5s
        stats uri /httpstats
        stats realm HTTPS proxy stats
        stats auth https:user1@pass1

listen HTTPS
bind 0.0.0.0:5008
        mode tcp
        balance roundrobin
        http-check expect status 200

server s1 127.0.0.1:8000 check
server s2 35.46.232.130:26000 check
```

Upd.: It appears to be an issue woth some type of SYN-flood:
I couldn't see any service listening because there was no service. I've checked all connections with port in subject and realized there are few of them in `SYN_SENT` state:
`tcp    SYN-SENT   0      1          <server_ext_IP>:5008         <some_IP>:16767`
Filtered `ss -tulpan` output by `<some_IP>` and realized there are tons of connections from this IP in same SYN_SENT state. Looks like some simple attack.

Upd.2:
after blocking flood I realised we still had connections with 5008 and 3310 port on local server:

```
tcp    SYN-SENT   0      1          <server_ext_IP>:5008       77.242.1.101:8080
```

But they were outgoing! grepped `ip:port` of the recipient and found them in nearby `haproxy-http2.cfg`.
the line in config was:

```
server pyhttps 77.242.1.101:8080 check
```

It appears i was unlucky enough so one service chose random port to check some server from its config and this port was conflicted with ports which wants to listen my other service.

Please advise: how to avoid such conflict?
I could:
1)  stop all haproxy services and start them all in one command -(minimizing failure chance) - it's a bad idea to stop working service manually
2) close ports in subject by firewall untill no connection on these ports is active and restart needed service - works, but takes some time and scripting
3) exclude important ports from ports which could be taken by services for outgoing connections.
Any idea how to achieve this result?

Answer (score 0):

It was a port misconfiguration: sysctl.conf contained a directive:

```
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65003
```

Which allows system to take a random local port number from 1024 to 65003 for outgoing connections. That was the reason I sufferred from a `cannot bind socket` error but didn't see any service listening on subject port.
To fix I have increased lower port to 6000 in sysctl.conf and reloaded sysctl settings with `sysctl -p`.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. below steps followed

1. check if already some process is bonded with this port. stop that service
2. disable SELinux or set to permissive mode.
   add line : setsebool -P haproxy_connect_any=1 to /etc/sysconfig/selinux file and reboot
3. also try to add net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind=1 in /etc/sysctl.conf
   and run #sysctl -p